# Adding static value to dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a dropdown menu that is generated in a different file. It is generated with a while loop, and I would like to add one static value ( Select contract ).

Right now a dropdown menu looks like this:

```
1234
4321
2323
3232
```

And I would like to make it like this:

```
Select contracr
1234
4321
2323
3232
```

Here is my code in index.php:

```
<select id="text2" name="text2">

</select>
```

And here is my code in process.php (where items are generated):

```
<?php
$selectedKey = $_GET['selected_key'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `1 received` WHERE Key = '".$selectedKey."'";
$run = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['Number']."'>".$row['Number']."</option>";
}
?>
```

Ajax code:

```
<script>
$("select#select2").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "selected_key=" + $(this).val(),
        success: function(result) {
            $("select#text2").html(result);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: By the way... you really should be using PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: you should cast that `$selectedKey` to an int to close a big security hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this.

Just add an extra option to the `<select>` - i.e. a literal value, not something PHP generates - before you add all the other values from the database. Give it a value like "0" or "NotSelected", then check for that in your validation routines.

Oh, and as an unrelated issue, don't do this:

```
$selectedKey = $_GET['selected_key'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `1 received` WHERE Key = '".$selectedKey."'";
```

You're opening yourself to SQL injections. If you don't know what that is, look it up. You should be using prepared/parameterized queries for this. Both the PDO and mysqli extensions have this capability, so you should be using one of those instead of the mysql extension, which has been deprecated (i.e. "this will be removed from the language soon, so stop using it") in the latest version of PHP.

---

Update:

Based on the fact that you're updating the HTML directly using an AJAX request to get new content for the `<select>` element, you need to move the `<option>` item I mentioned to be part of the script you call in your AJAX request.

Specifically, you should do it directly before your `foreach` loop:

```
<?php
$selectedKey = $_GET['selected_key'];

// DO SOME VALIDATION ON $selectedKey here
// Remember what I said about SQL injection and using mysqli/PDO

$query = "SELECT * FROM `1 received` WHERE Key = '".$selectedKey."'";
$run = mysql_query($query);
echo "<option value='NotSelected'>Select Contract</option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['Number']."'>".$row['Number']."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Well I am trying to add one <select> by myself, but the dropdown is generated in a different file and thats what confuses me.

Comment: @user1914940 - I think you need to clarify what you mean by the drop down being generated in a different file.

Comment: @user1914940 It doesn't matter where the rest of the `<option>` elements are generated. Since this `<option>` needs to be the first one, you can just add it directly after the `<select>`.

Comment: You can see in my original question, <select> tags are in index.php, but while loop that generates dropdown menu is in process.php

Comment: @AgentConundrum If I put my static value after <select> the it will be generated everytime while loop runs, I only need it once.

Comment: @user1914940 Right, so just add `<option value="NotSelected">Select Contract</option>` in your `index.php` file directly below the `<select id="text2" name="text2">` line. In the longer run, you should try harder to separate logic from presentation, but that's a bigger topic than we're covering here.

Comment: @user1914940 Wait, what? Why would it be generated every time the loop runs?

Comment: @AgentConundrum Ok, if I do that it will only appear when I visit the website. As soon as I select something from first dropdown menu this will disappear.

Comment: @user1914940 I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I suspect you're missing something important from your question.

Comment: @AgentConundrum No no...I have 2 dropdown menus. In the first one they select item and in the second they select contract. Each item has different contracts. Now I see Select contract only when I first wisit the website, as soon as I select one item the list of contracts shows, but no Select contract at the top of the list.

Comment: @user1914940 - This is the *least* clear explanation of a problem. Can you try explaining this in a different way??

Comment: @AgentConundrum No, thats how it is. 2 dropdowns, 1st item, 2nd contract. I would like static option on the top of second one.

Comment: @user1914940 So is this an AJAX sort of thing, where selecting one thing triggers a request to populate the second? In that case, you just move the `<option value="NotSelected">` portion to be displayed immediately before the loop in the part that's populating the new values. This definitely seems like a sub-optimal way to accomplish this though.

Comment: @AgentConundrum Hmm...ok. I have 2 dropdown menus. The first one has the list of items. The second one has a list of contracts for each item. When user first visit a website they select an item, and the second dropdown menu updates itself with the list of contracts for that item. Now what I need to do is add a static option at the top of that list (of contracts). The code you provided works only when they visit the website, but as soon as they select an item it is gone, and only the contracts are shown.

Comment: @Nicarus I think he's trying to do a dynamic form where selecting an option from one dropdown triggers a request to populate a second dropdown. For whatever reason, the `<select>` element is created separately from its `<option>` elements. There's a lot that's odd here.

Comment: @user1914940 - Can you confirm whether or not you are using this with AJAX as AgentConundrum mentions in his comment?

Comment: @Nicarus Yes, I use ajax.

Comment: @user1914940 So you're just returning a new set of options as part of the AJAX response, right? In that case, just add the literal `<option>` value I mentioned, but do it directly before the `foreach` loop in the script you call in the AJAX request.

Comment: @AgentConundrum I dont understand...let me update my original question with my ajax code.

Comment: @user1914940 - Did you write this code or did you inherit it?

Comment: @Nicarus No, someone here helped me with it.

Comment: @user1914940 I understood what you were doing when I realized you were using an AJAX request. My answer is still the same as what I've been saying in these past few comments. Let me update my answer with an example, which is pretty much identical to what others have already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$selectedKey = $_GET['selected_key'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `1 received` WHERE Key = '".$selectedKey."'";
$run = mysql_query($query);

echo "<option value='0'>Select Contractor</option>"; //Simply add this

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['Number']."'>".$row['Number']."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, since this is in another file it will not appear in dropdown menu.

Comment: @user1914940 - Huh? That doesn't make sense to me. How is it that you are populating the drop down not if now using the script your provide and I modified?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?php
$selectedKey = $_GET['selected_key'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `1 received` WHERE Key = '".$selectedKey."'";
$run = mysql_query($query);
$str = "<option value='0'>Select anyone</option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $str .= "<option value='".$row['Number']."'>".$row['Number']."</option>";
}
echo $str;
?>
```

Likt this you can add static options

Comment: This will add Select anyone at the end of dropdown menu, need it at the top :)

Comment: It will show Select anyone as the first option. .Then it will populate other options from your loop..

Answer (score -2):

```
please used this code......
<?php
$selectedKey = $_GET['selected_key'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `1 received` WHERE Key = '".$selectedKey."'";
$run = mysql_query($query);

$str = "<option value='0'>Select Contractor</option>"; //Simply add this

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $str .= "<option value='".$row['Number']."'>".$row['Number']."</option>";
}
?>


echo $str variable into your select box like this:-


<select id="text2" name="text2">
<?php echo $str;?>
</select>
```

Comment: So do you normally copy and paste other people's answers and post them as your own??

Comment: no i have not copy pasted please see properly i have concatenated the variable and then echo it into select box this is what my logic was please see it properly.....

Comment: The identical comment '//Simply add this' with Nicarus' earlier solution is a complete coincidence is it?